# Sequence of vectors $(x_n)$ such that $||x_m-x_n|| \geqslant 1$ whenever $n \neq m$ in $\infty$-dim normed vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

In an infinite-dimensional normed vector space, show that there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ with $||x_n|| \leqslant 1$ such that $||x_n-x_m|| \geqslant1$ whenever $n \neq m$.

This is an early exercise on my undergraduate functional analysis course so I think some elementary solution is expected. If I am not mistaken this is equivalent to asking for an infinite collection of disjoint balls of size $1/2$ with centre inside the unit ball. Intuitively if I had an orthogonal basis for my space then I could go along the axes and add a ball, but not enough structure for orthogonal basis in the question. I don't really know all too much about $\infty$ dimensional spaces generally, to be honest. Any pointers/hints appreciated.

Comment: Have a look  at [Riesz lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma)

Comment: The hint given above is the way to go here. Otherwise try looking at the proof of "the closed ball of norm 1 is compact iff the space is finite dimensional". The argument is pretty much the same. If you cannot understand any of these, edit your question and we can discuss it further:)

Comment: Thank you both, I will consider this hint and view this question again later. Unfortunately a lot of other maths is keeping me busy

Comment: I've now posted an answer, if there are any incorrect details please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argue by induction:

Let $V$ be an infinite-dimensional normed vector space. Suppose $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\} \subset$ $V$ is such that $\|x_i\| =1$ and $\|x_k-x_m\| \geqslant 1$ $\forall k,m \in\{1,2,...,n\}$. Then let $V_n=\text{span}(x_1,...,x_n)$.

Let $w_{n+1} \notin V_n$. Then consider $V_n \ \cap \bar{B}(w_{n+1}, \inf_{x \in V_n} \|w_{n+1}-x\|+1)$. This intersection is closed and bounded therefore compact (as normed vector spaces have the Heine Borel property, and the set considered is finite dimensional). Thus in this intersection, $\inf_{x \in V_n} \|w_{n+1}-x\|=z$ is attained (because for a compact set $X$ and a continuous function $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$, $f$ is bounded and attains its bounds in $X$, and in particular the norm function is continuous).

Now let $$x_{n+1} = \frac{w_{n+1}-z}{\|w_{n+1}-z\|}$$

Claim that $\|x_{n+1}-x\| \geqslant \|x_{n+1}\|=1$, $\forall x \in V_{n}$. Proceed by contradiction: suppose instead that $\|x_{n+1}-x\|<1$. Then consider $z'=z+\|w_{n+1}-z\|x$. Note that $z' \in V_{n}$ since $V_{n}$ is a subspace and $z \in V_{n}$, $x \in V_{n}$. Observe that

$\|w_{n+1}-z'\|=\|w_{n+1}-z-\|w_{n+1}-z\|x\|=\|w_{n+1}-z\|\|\frac{w_{n+1}-z}{\|w_{n+1}-z\|}-x\|=\|w_{n+1}-z\|\|x_{n+1}-x\|<\|w_{n+1}-z\|.$

But this is a contradiction because $z$ minimised $\|w_{n+1}-x\|$ over $V_n \ \cap \bar{B}(w_{n+1},\inf_{x \in V_n} \|w_{n+1}-x\|+1)$, so $z$ was minimal over $V_n$ too (certainly anything that lives in $V_n$ but lives outside the ball has a greater distance to $w_{n+1}$). So have the desired result.